# Does wso2 emm provide space isolation?

Tags: security, wso2, wso2-iot

A BYOD security solution must meet some requirements, one Of them is Space isolation.

Space isolation: it must be able to isolate personal space and corporate space on a BYOD so that different security policies can be applied.

I would like to know whether or not this EMM provide space isolation or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not right now.

My view is that the OS will soon provide isolation and we prefer for that over inventing something. Most of the other MDMs provide isolation by providing a library which must be used by app developers to achieve space isolation. If you absolutely need it right now then yes that's fine but what it means is you can't use any stock apps in an isolated way.

OS level isolation will solve that .. Samsung Knox is the first shot.

Comment: Please could you clarify if this isolation is provided out of the box or we also need to use a library/SDK with EMM?